# How to prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(a;q)_i}{(q;q)_i}\frac{(b;q)_{n-i}}{(q;q)_{n-i}}a^{n-i}=\frac{(ab;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}$?

Tags: binomial-theorem, q-series, q-analogs

By Cauchy identity, $${}_1\phi_0(a;—;q,z)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(a;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}z^n=\frac{(az;q)_{\infty}}{(z;q)_\infty},\quad|z|<1,|q|<1,$$
we can obtain the $q-$analogue of $(1-z)^{-a}(1-z)^{-b}=(1-z)^{-a-b},$ $${}_1\phi_0(a;—;q,z){}_1\phi_0(b;—;q,az)={}_1\phi_0(ab;—;q,z),$$
which is $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(a;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}z^n\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{(b;q)_m}{(q;q)_m}(az)^m=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(ab;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}z^n.$$

Comparing the coefficients of $z$ in the both side of equation above, the identity in the title can be established as
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(a;q)_i}{(q;q)_i}\frac{(b;q)_{n-i}}{(q;q)_{n-i}}a^{n-i}=\frac{(ab;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}.$$

However, what I really concern is that there is any possible for us to prove this identity directly without utilizing Cauchy identity. Maybe we can use **mathematical induction** on *$n$* or some other **combinatorial** or **algebraic** proofs?

Comment: I don't really know how to progress but the Jackson Q Derivative is a good tool for this. It's a linear operator that does simple symbol shuffling for Q series, and if you could show that taking a Q derivative w.r.t A and B in your expression leaves both sides equal, then you conclude that they have a constant difference, then verify they are equal for n = 0 --> the constant is 0 --> they are equal

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-derivative